# How do I create a target geometry to use with JTS GeometrySnapper?

Tags: snapping, jts-topology-suite

I am dealing with geospatial queries on a database. The query returns all data sets within an arbitrary bounding box, given a point associated with the data set is within this bounding box.

Since the bounding boxes provided have very high precision, I was not able to apply caching mechanisms based on the bounding boxes latitude and longitude values. In order to be able to cache queries, I thought it would be a smart idea to normalize bounding boxes before querying the database.

My initial idea was to simply truncate lat/lon decimal places, but this approach doesn't allow for configuration of the precision.

Later, I found [JTS GeometrySnapper](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/operation/overlay/snap/GeometrySnapper.html) which allows to snap to arbitrary geometries.

I would love to create a geometry that allows me to snap to a grid comprising of lines every *n* meters both in latitude and longitude. How do I construct such a geometry?

This is my approach so far:

```
  private def sanitizeBoundingBox(boundaries: BoundingBox): Geometry = {
    val precisionModel: PrecisionModel = new PrecisionModel()
    val geometryFactory: GeometryFactory = new GeometryFactory(precisionModel, 4326)
    val box: Geometry = geometryFactory.toGeometry(new Envelope(boundaries.minLongitude, boundaries.maxLongitude, boundaries.minLatitude, boundaries.maxLatitude))
    val snapper = new GeometrySnapper(box)
    snapper.snapTo(???, ???)
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this scenario, I would suggest using the JTS [`GeometryPrecisionReducer`](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/precision/GeometryPrecisionReducer.html) class rather than [`GeometrySnapper`](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/operation/overlay/snap/GeometrySnapper.html). `GeometrySnapper` is intended for snapping one geometry to another.  If you wanted to use `GeometrySnapper`, you could generate a fishnet grid at your desired precision level to snap to.  But `GeometryPrecisionReducer` provides the same result without needing to generate the grid.

Also, just an observation on the argument you're using for the `PrecisionModel` constructor (5).  Just making sure you're aware that that is not equivalent to number of decimals, but rather scale.  From the `PrecisionModel` class documentation:

> For example, to specify 3 decimal places of precision, use a scale factor of 1000. To specify -3 decimal places of precision (i.e. rounding to the nearest 1000), use a scale factor of 0.001.

Comment: Makes much more sense. Thank you! And yes: I was very much mistaken about the PrecisionModel constructor (I did adapt the example to make it less confusing).